# How do I loop through multidimensional arrays with forEach or .reduce?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, multidimensional-array, foreach, reduce

I am trying to write a function called `twoDimensionalProduct(array)` that takes in a 2D array of
numbers as an argument. The function should return the total product of all
numbers multiplied together.

I can solve this using **nested traditional for loops**. This was my solution:

```
function twoDimensionalProduct(array){
  let prod = 1;
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
      let subArr = array[i];
      for(let j = 0; j < subArr.length; j++){
          prod *= subArr[j]
      }
  }
  return prod
}

let arra1 = [
  [6, 4],
  [5],
  [3, 1]
];
console.log(twoDimensionalProduct(arra1)); // 360
```

I am trying to figure out how to solve the same problems using the forEach or reduce method.
Can someone help me with the best approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map the array to multiply within elements using reduce and finally reduce on the outer array

```
const prod = arra1.map((arr) => {
    return arr.reduce((a, b) => a * b);
}).reduce((a, b) => a * b);
console.log(prod);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like one liners, here's how you do it in one line.

```
let arra1 = [
  [6, 4],
  [5],
  [3, 1]
];

let sum = arra1.flat(2).reduce((sum, val) => sum * val);
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Flatten the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and then [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) over the numbers.

```js
function twoDimensionalProduct(array){
  return array.flat().reduce((acc, c) => acc * c);
}

let arra1 = [[6, 4],[5],[3, 1]];

console.log(twoDimensionalProduct(arra1));
```